# how to understand "hand me into one of the reunion scene"?

Tags: phrases

A sentence from ACT reading:
"Suddenly, as I descended the two steps from the train, the porter hands me into one of the reunion scenes. 'Hi, honey, how was the trip? Did you get any sleep?' 'A little. Been waiting long?' 'Long enough to beat your dad in two games of cribbage...' Glancing back at the train windows. I imagine I am looking into eyes hidden behind mirrored sunglasses."

I could not find the definition of the phrase "hand somebody into..," so what does the independent clause mean?

Comment: more context needed, please?

Comment: Looks like a tupo to me.